# trying to get max from List is throwing Target Invocation Exception

Tags: java

I was trying to return the list by setting the object which has maximum value.

```
List<One> myList1 = getDetails();
```

I want to check "family" list and keep the element which has maximum of "fId" out of exisitng elements.

Below is the sample code tried, it is throwing **TargetInvocationException**

```
myList1.forEach(myList1 -> myList1.getFamily().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Family::getFId))
        .stream().findFirst()
        .orElse(null));
```

Sample class:

```
@Data
class One{
    private Long mId;
    private String mPolicyName;
    private List<Family> family;

}

@Data
class Family{
    private Long fId;
    private String fname;
    private String fStatus;
}
```

Comment: Your problem probably has nothing to do with the algorithm for finding the max element, but when Java tries to execute a getter from your JSON parser library something goes wrong. Can you post also the callstack?

Comment: Also interesting - which library are you using to parse the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things wrong. First, the `forEach()` doesn't do anything. Second, the `Comparator` is comparing `fId` which is an attribute of `Family`, not `One`. Finally, `max()` returns an `Optional` and you don't need to `.stream().findFirst()`.

Assuming that class `One` has a setter method `setFamily(List<Family> family)`, you can do:

```
myList1.forEach(one -> one.setFamily(one.getFamily().stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Family::getFId))
                .stream().toList()));
```

Comment: When tried to implement the above, it is showing compilation error 'comparing(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends U>, java.util.Comparator<? super U>)' in 'java.util.Comparator' cannot be applied to '(<method reference>, java.util.Comparator<com.sam.test.Family>)'

Comment: You didn't post classes `One` and `Family`, so I had to assume their structures.

Comment: sorry.Just updated the post with the classes. Please see One.java in the post. It is different from the one you have edited and posted.

Comment: Please see the One.class structure is different from the one i want. Posted the model classes in the post.

Comment: I updated the answer with the classes you added to the question.